# Session variables turning into arrays when I put them into variables

Tags: php, session

I have a session for login data, and I am trying to take it and put it into a variable to shorten whenever I want to echo or use the ID, Username, or Email. What is happening is that now I have it in a variable, but when I echo it, it shows it in an array.

Here is my variable data.

```
$User = htmlentities(ucwords($_SESSION['user']['username']));
$Email = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

If I echo any of these, it returns "Array".

**EDIT**

I fixed my solution by changing how I get my $_SESSION data, and using unset to get rid of the array. Now I can just do this,

```
$User  = $_SESSION['user']["username"];
$Email = $_SESSION['user']["email"];
```

Thank you for reminding me about how I'm even getting my session data in the first place =]

Comment: How are you setting them, and what does `var_dump($User); var_dump($Email);` print?

Comment: The original values are arrays then. Please post the code where you set the in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: It returns "string(8) "Necrohhh" | string(23) "myemail@google.com""

Comment: @Necro.: Sorry, I meant `$_SESSION['user']['username']` and `$_SESSION['user']['email']`, respectively. But if that's what gets printed out... you're not `echo`ing them right :D

Comment: @Necro. Then the values you are attempting to echo are not these.

Comment: When I echo htmlentities(ucwords($_SESSION['user']['username'])); for example, it returns it perfect. Why does it not use the htmlentities to just give me the username once in the variable?

Comment: @Necro. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I mean, when I echo htmlentities($_SESSION["user"]["username"]); it returns my name in plain text. Why is it that when I place it in a variable $User in this case, it does not use htmlentities to strip the plain text?

Comment: @Necro. I am guessing you are looking at the output in the browser? If so, view the _page source_ to see the encoded entities.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using classes, where you specify all your variables, maybe try this:

```
$User  = $_SESSION['user']->username;
echo $User;
```

where `user` is your class and `username` is your variable
WHen you add it to your session, you need to do soething like this:

```
    $_SESSION['user'] = new user();
    $_SESSION['user']->username= 'whatever value it is';
```

Comment: This returns Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'